# How to connect private Git repo to Jenkins server on windows?

Tags: windows, git, github, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have been trying to connenct a private Git repo to my Jenkins server which runs on a Windows. I have installed the GitHub plugin and I can get it working when the repo is public, but when I switch to private repo it gets stuck on the

```
> git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/-Username-/-repoName-.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: No error messages?

Comment: Nope no error messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem! I fixed it by changing the service of Jenkins from local system to local user. Beware that the service doesn't always start well. I would recommend changing it from automatic to automatic delayed. This will give your PC the time to login and then start this service.
You can find services in *Windows icon* > Typing Services & opening it > Press J to instantly go to the Jenkins service and the rest is self explaineble.

Comment: Yes this fixed the problem.